# Marshaling C# struct for C++ dll function

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, marshalling

I have a c++ dll function that takes as a parameter a pointer to this struct:

```
struct tLBCSHREP_PARAMS
{
  BYTE Ps;
  char* Shift;
  char* Cashier;
  char* CashRegNr;
};
```

, where BYTE is an 8 bit integer.

I am calling this c++ function in C# code. I have created C# equivalent for that c++ struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct tLBCSHREP_PARAMS
    {
        public byte Ps;
        public IntPtr Shift;
        public IntPtr Cashier;
        public IntPtr CashRegNr;
    };
```

I am creating an instatce of this struct and then a pointer:

```
tLBCSHREP_PARAMS p_tLBCSHREP_PARAMS = new tLBCSHREP_PARAMS();
 p_tLBCSHREP_PARAMS = rapkas;

 rapkas.Ps = (byte)ps;
 rapkas.Shift =  Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(shift);
 rapkas.Cashier = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(cashier);
 rapkas.CashRegNr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(cashregnr);

IntPtr ptrLBTSRLN = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rapkas));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(rapkas, ptrLBTSRLN, false);
```

After passing pointer to the dll funcion I get error: 0xC0000001. To my knowledge it means segmentation fault, so probably struct is not created in right way.
I have tried many times adding differrent attributes to the struct,
adding '[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]' phrase before 'public byte Ps;' variable and many more. Nothing worked ;(

Comment: Could you share the signature of the C++ function you call, and the p/invoke C# part?

Comment: It does not mean "segmentation fault".  That error code is never used as an exception code, only practical usage is as an "it did not work" error number.  But who knows, native code can do anything at all.  If you don't have a telephone then you'll have to debug it.

Comment: @Dirk
C++ function is defined as:
**typedef int  Typ_LBCSHREP(tLBCSHREP_PARAMS *)**; 
I have an acces to a c++ file that was using that dll function and it worked well as far as I know.
In C# I have created a delegate: 
**public delegate int Typ_LBCSHREP(IntPtr ptr)**
This delegate is initialised with function from dll:
**LBCshrep_D = new Typ_LBCSHREP(LBCSHREP);**
LBCSHREP is created this way: 
**[DllImport("ThermalServiceLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int LBCSHREP(IntPtr ptr);**

Comment: @Dirk
Invoking part:
IntPtr ptrLBTSRLN = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rapkas));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(rapkas, ptrLBTSRLN, false);
int blad = LBCshrep_D(ptrLBTSRLN);

Comment: Just a few hints to simplify it: use `string` instead of `IntPtr` for the `char *` members. And change the signature of the p/invoke to take the `tLBCSHREP_PARAMS` as a parameter. I don't think manually marshalling is necessary for a simple struct like that.